# Cannot make a vector of structs in C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm trying to do the following:

```
struct Code
{
    GF2X generator;
    vector<GF2X> codeWords;
};

vector<Code> allCodes;
```

However, I end up with this error:

```
error: template argument for 'template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator' uses local type 'main()::Code'|
```

I'm completely lost as to what this means. This is also my first time programming in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++03 local classes (classes defined inside a function) cannot be used as template arguments. That restriction was lifted in C++11, but if your compiler does not have support for this feature you can always move the type definition outside of the function at namespace level.

Answer (score 3):

Define the struct outside (but before) your `int main()`.

Comment: Oh, so it was a local type because I declared it within main? It seems like this makes stucts similar to java classes, but with no member functions.

Comment: @Teofrostus: In C++ a `struct` is exactly the same as a class with a single distinction: the default access specifier is public. That is, `struct`s can have member functions, including virtual member functions, inherit or be derived, have constructors and destructors...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted all your code, but I'm guessing that you put `struct Code ...` inside your main function. Try moving it above the start of main.